# Controlling Facebook oauth login experience

Tags: facebook, oauth

I'm building a Facebbook application that uses the Facebook oauth login.  I see some existing sites that have a single-page experience that combines application authorization with asking for permissions.  But when I build my application, I'm seeing a two-page authorization dialog: application authorization and basic permissions come on the first screen, the second screen asks for additional permissions.

I'd like to get to a single-screen dialog, similar to the one shown on this page:

```
 http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
```

but that's not what I'm seeing, even though I use the URL from that page, and even though I use the same Oauth redirect URL that I see in another app that shows the dialog as I want it.

Anyone have any ideas on how to have the older app authentication dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: that's the way it works now.  Facebook changed things.  Go figure.

Facebook has changed the way the auth dialog works.  It seems like they are trying to discourage use of publish_stream and other permissions and make it easier for users to grant the open graph publish_actions permission.

From the recent blog post:

> Added functionality to the publish_actions permission
>
> When we turn on the new auth dialog, we will also add some of the most frequently requested permissions to publish_actions to make the permission more robust and improve conversion. publish_actions now includes the ability to post status updates on the authenticated user’s own timeline, tag photos, publish photos and videos. Other actions such as posting to a friend's timeline still require the use of publish_stream.
>
> Adding these common permissions to publish_actions eliminates the need for extended permissions and the second screen of the auth dialog for the majority of timeline apps built with the Open Graph. This makes the auth process clearer to new users and should improve conversion rates. Additionally, approved Open Graph actions are no longer required for the publish_actions permission. Apps should only ask for the stream_publish permission if they absolutely need functionality not present in publish_actions.

See this blog post for full details and references:  https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/02/enhanced-auth-dialog-and-updates-to-permissions/

Subscribing to the Facebook devleoper blog and monitoring the platform roadmap at https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ are good ways to see these changes coming.